# Two questions about copy_pte_range() in kernel

Tags: linux, kernel, x86

I've been trying to understand how `fork()` works and finally arrived at `copy_pte_range()`. Most of the functions are understandable but few are quite questionable.

**Kernel**: 4.14.84

```c
static int copy_pte_range(struct mm_struct *dst_mm, struct mm_struct *src_mm,
           pmd_t *dst_pmd, pmd_t *src_pmd, struct vm_area_struct *vma,
           unsigned long addr, unsigned long end)
{
    pte_t *orig_src_pte, *orig_dst_pte;
    pte_t *src_pte, *dst_pte;
    spinlock_t *src_ptl, *dst_ptl;
    int progress = 0;
    int rss[NR_MM_COUNTERS];
    swp_entry_t entry = (swp_entry_t){0};

again:
    init_rss_vec(rss);

    dst_pte = pte_alloc_map_lock(dst_mm, dst_pmd, addr, &dst_ptl);
    if (!dst_pte)
        return -ENOMEM;
    src_pte = pte_offset_map(src_pmd, addr);
    src_ptl = pte_lockptr(src_mm, src_pmd);
    spin_lock_nested(src_ptl, SINGLE_DEPTH_NESTING);
    orig_src_pte = src_pte;
    orig_dst_pte = dst_pte;
    arch_enter_lazy_mmu_mode();

    do {
        /*
         * We are holding two locks at this point - either of them
         * could generate latencies in another task on another CPU.
         */
        if (progress >= 32) {
            progress = 0;
            if (need_resched() ||
                spin_needbreak(src_ptl) || spin_needbreak(dst_ptl))
                break;
        }
        if (pte_none(*src_pte)) {
            progress++;
            continue;
        }
        entry.val = copy_one_pte(dst_mm, src_mm, dst_pte, src_pte,
                            vma, addr, rss);
        if (entry.val)
            break;
        progress += 8;
    } while (dst_pte++, src_pte++, addr += PAGE_SIZE, addr != end);

    arch_leave_lazy_mmu_mode();
    spin_unlock(src_ptl);
    pte_unmap(orig_src_pte);
    add_mm_rss_vec(dst_mm, rss);
    pte_unmap_unlock(orig_dst_pte, dst_ptl);
    cond_resched();

    if (entry.val) {
        if (add_swap_count_continuation(entry, GFP_KERNEL) < 0)
            return -ENOMEM;
        progress = 0;
    }
    if (addr != end)
        goto again;
    return 0;
}
```

**Questions**
1. In the `do {} while()`, what is the purpose of `progress` variable?
2. After `do {} while()`, there is `pte_unmap(orig_src_pte);` Why is it needed? This is the process of `fork()`. Based on my knowledge, the parent `pte(orig_src_pte)` should still be mapped because the process is based on Copy-on-Write so I guess it doesn't have to be unmapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The `progress` variable measures the cost of the operations performed under locks, and avoids holding those locks for too long. At most every 32 calls to `pte_none`, or 4 calls to `copy_one_pte` (which is expensive), or a combination thereof, the function checks whether a reschedule is needed, or if the locks are requested elsewhere; if so, it releases the locks and allows a reschedule. The function continues where it left off, thanks to the jump to `again`.
2. The unmap call doesn’t unmap the original PTE in the source process, it undoes the effects of the `src_pte = pte_offset_map(src_pmd, addr);` line at the start of the function.